# android edittext doesn't lose focus

Tags: android, listview, focus, android-edittext

I have listview which contains one edittext, one textview and one imageview. Initially edittext is gone and textview is visible.
My aim is if user clicks the imageview, textview will be switched to the edittext and user will be able to enter the new text.After that if user clicks on imageview again new text will be updated.
My problem is after I click edittext and write sth listview loses focus and I cant click to imageview again. (even listview 's OnItemClick method is not called). How can I get over it ?

Comment: `setFocusable(false)` for Edittext after clicking on the image

Comment: @Pragnani I can click the imageview after i click the edittext and leave it empty. But if I write something to edittext I can no longer click the imageview. I set an onclicklistener to edittext as you said listview.requestfocus(),listview.setfocusable(true),imageview.setfocusable(false). but nothing changed

Comment: @barisemreefe Post your code, and also try setting on focus change listener to the edittext when the edittext lose focus just setFocusable(false) for edittext